# Change Plone workflow

Tags: python, plone

By default Files haven't workflow

So i put them the simple publication workflow (private -> submit -> publish)

I want the authenticated users could not modify the file when it is published

(on Plone 4.0.7)

Comment: Have you updated the security settings? ( ZMI > portal_workflow @ bottom of the page)

Comment: portal_workflow/updateRoleMappings can simply modify the default workflow attached to the content type

Comment: @FranklinKingma The default 'simple publication workflow' doesn't prevent editing when published.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it does for authenticated users, doesn't it? not for manager, owner, site administrator and editor.

Comment: @FranklinKingma True, which makes me think there is more to this question.

Comment: Simple publication workflow doesn't prevent editing for authenticated users too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this:

- Go to `portal_workflow` -> `contents`
- Copy & Paste `simple_publication_workflow`
- Rename `copy_of_simple_publication_workflow` to something else (eg. `my_files_workflow`)
- Go to `my_files_workflow` -> `States` -> `published` -> `Permissions`
- Uncheck the unwanted Permissions

Now you can assign this new workflow to your files.